# How to add reference of one schema to another in Mongoose and inserting data by json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I am writing a node.js app where I have two mongoose schemas *Wallet* and *User*.

- I want to add ***Wallet as a reference to User*** and pass the appropiate json from POSTMAN. This is like adding a reference of one class in another in OOPs and foreign key concept in RDBMS.

I have written the schemas like this:

**user.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {type: String},
    isAdmin: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    password: {type: String},
    name: {type: String},
    wallet: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Wallet'} //see here
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Is the way I referenced wallet above, correct? If not, can you tell me the right way?

**wallet.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var walletSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    money: {type: Number, default: 0, min: 0},  
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Wallet', walletSchema);
```

The following is my user route file.

**userRoute.js**

```
router.route('/user')

.post(function (req, res) {

    var user = new User();

    user.userId = req.body.userId;
    user.password = req.body.password;
    user.name = req.body.name;
    user.isAdmin = req.body.isAdmin;
    user.wallet = req.body.wallet; // see here

    user.save(function(err, user){
        if(err){
            res.json({ message: 'Failure' });
            return false;           
        }
        res.json({ message: 'Success' });
    });     
})
```

Is the way I have assigned wallet to the user object correct? If not can you tell me the right way?

Now I want to post raw json from Postman. What will the json look like?

Answer (score 3):

`user.wallet = req.body.wallet` won't work.

As far as `User` is concerned `user.wallet` is just a simple field of the type ObjectId that store a 24 char hex string-like object: `522abc...`.

This "reference" is actually a higher level interpretation of Mongoose.

That's why you can't directly do `user.wallet = req.body.wallet`. You have to do something like this:

```
var user = new User();
…
// user.wallet = req.body.wallet; // won't work
var wallet = new Wallet(req.body.wallet) // because Wallet too is a Schema just like User
user.wallet = wallet.id;
…
```

Comment: Ok, I got this part. Now can you give me a sample json that I can post? I want to see the json structure..how to pass the wallet in the json.

Comment: I actually didn't understand that part. Can you elaborate or give some context? Do you mean what your `req.body.wallet` should look like? Or are you talking about sending it to client with `res.json`?

Comment: Ya I mean what req.body.wallet look like while posting in json. For eg. {
    "userId": "xxyyzz",
    "password": "12345",
    "name": "Utsav",
    "isAdmin": "true",
    "wallet": **here is my confusion..how to write this wallet json**
}

Comment: It should look exactly how you've defined it in your schema. `{ money: 123 }`. And if you only have a `money` field in your form (i.e. `req.body.money`) then you would do `var wallet = new Wallet({money: req.body.money})`. The main thing is still that it should be exactly like how you've defined it in your schema, just like how you're creating the `user` is how you would create your `wallet`. And then simply `user.wallet = wallet.id`

Comment: Could you please share your code with me. I am having same problem right now.